# When a discontinuous function is integrated, how are we including and excluding a certain element at the same time?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

consider :-  $$\int_1^3 \lfloor t\rfloor\,\mathrm dt$$

the standard way to integrate this is to split it into :-
$$\int_1^2 \lfloor t\rfloor\,\mathrm dt +\int_2^3 \lfloor t\rfloor\, \mathrm dt$$
I understand that $2$ isn't a part of the first integral's "domain" as $\lfloor 2\rfloor=2$ and not $1$, but how are we including $2$ in the bounds of the first and 2nd including without either excluding it completely or counting the same element twice?

Comment: The set $\{2\}$ is of measure zero, so it has no effect on the value of the integral.

Comment: @K.defaoite. Understood. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We do not count, we integrate. And indeed, single (or even finitely many) points do not matter in integration.
If $f\colon[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ is integrable and $g\colon[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ is a function such that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all but finitely many $x\in[a,b]$, then $g$ is integrable and
$$ \int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^bg(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: Oh, I see, and this follows from the fact that between any two reals, there are infinitely many reals?

Comment: @fhhh That follows from the definition of the Lebesgue measure, the one being implicitly used in the integrals above. For some other measures a single point may have a positive mass. But the Lebesgue measure gives zero weight to all rational numbers (because it’s a countable set) or even some infinite uncountable sets, like the cantor set.

Comment: oh, OK. What do you mean by measure and mass here? I have never seen those terms in any of my classes

Comment: Here the measure is just "length". The length of a single point (or finitely many points) is zero hence they don't matter.

Comment: oh, I see. Thanks!

Comment: Or even *countably* many. Or better still, **uncountably** many for some choice examples (eg. Cantor set).

Comment: @K.defaoite, I see, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter if we exclude it or count it twice; the technique works because adding or removing finitely many elements from the domain of integration doesn't change the result. The proof of this fact depends on the definition of integration you're working with, but the idea is that the corresponding "area under the curve" is zero.

Comment: So using the definition that the integral is simply the opposite of the derivative, the area excluded/included is essentially negligible?

Comment: @fhhh Well, the *indefinite* integral is the same as the antiderivative, but we're talking about *definite* integrals, which measure the area under the graph of a function. (The two standard definitions are the Riemann integral and the Lebesgue integral - see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral).) Notice that the region directly above and/or below a single point in the plane (corresponding to a single point in the domain of $f$) has zero area.

Comment: oh, I see.thanks!